# How to calculate sample mean and variance given the confidence interval for the normal?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, variance, confidence-interval

A random sample of size n=16 is taken from a random variable X~N(mu, sigma), with variance unknown. The 95% confidence interval for mu (44.7, 49.9).

What are the values of the sample mean and the variance? (X bar and S)

I got X bar to be 47.3.

I then got: 44.7 = 47.3 - S/(sqrt 16)* t(15,.025) for S=20.4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have gotten the mean right, it is the average of the end points.

$$\bar{x} - k S = 44.7$$

$$\bar{x} + k S = 44.7$$

where $k$ is known to you.

Since you already know $\bar{x}$, you can now solve for $\sigma$ in terms of $k$ and $\bar{x}$.

Comment: I then got: 44.7 = 47.3 - S/(sqrt 16)* t(15,.025) for S=20.4